# Function with multiple parameters in Python

Tags: python, function, file-io, parameters

I'm supposed to define a function that has 3 parameters, a path, a string and an integer. The path will describe the location of a file, and the string will be written into the file as many times as the integer.

```
def param(path, x: str, y: int)
    string = open(path, "a")
    string.writelines(y + "\n")
```

I've managed to write a path and print a string into that file, but I'm not able to use the integer parameter for my task. Can someone please help out with an easy to understand explanation as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
def write_lines(path,string,number):
    with open(path,"a+") as file:
        for i in range(number):
            file.write(string+"\n")
write_lines('logins.txt',"hello",5)
```

However, this won't truncate or overwrite the file. If you want that too:

```
def write_lines(path,string,number=1,truncate='yes'):
    with open(path,"a+") as file:
        if truncate.lower()=="yes":
            file.seek(0)
            file.truncate()
    
        for i in range(number):
            file.write(string+"\n")

write_lines('login.txt',"ello",5,'yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

please find inline comments

```py
def param(path, x: str, y: int):
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines((x+'\n' for _ in range(y))) #(y+'\n' for _ in range(n)) is a generator expression
        # for memory efficiency

# calling the function       
param('sample.txt', 'hello', n)
```